# Firebase Listener provides old data for some time even after data update

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime data built in the following structure for an android application, where Firebase Realtime listener is attached to the user node:

```
{user1:
  {
     data1:String,
     data2:String,
     data3:{
        child1: {
          grandChild11:String,
          grandChild12: Boolean

        }
        child2: {
          grandChild21:String,
          grandChild22: Boolean
         }

     }

   }

}
```

I create a list of grandChildi1, when I search for a user, if grandChildi2 is set to true.
This runs perfectly ok, in terms of populating the list. But when grandChildi2 is set to false, and I again search for the list of this user, grandChildi1 is still populated in the list during the first few occasions. After searching for the user a few more times, the list changes.

This looks like a cache issue to me. Any help on how this can be tackled.
If you need the code I can provide the same.

Comment: Instead of describing the problem, please show us the code that doesn't work the way you expect.